# GuzzleHttp and Memcached key

Tags: php, memcached, guzzle

I'm playing around with the GuzzleHttp client, GuzzleCacheMiddleware and Memcached.

The setup is calling the same url with different parameters.

This results in one! memcached hit, so I think the memcached key is created from the url and only the url.

Can I somehow change this behaviour, so the key includes a md5 of the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create your own CacheStrategy class. For example you can extend `PrivateCacheStrategy` class and override `getCacheKey` method which is responsible for creating the cache key.

https://github.com/Kevinrob/guzzle-cache-middleware/blob/master/src/Strategy/PrivateCacheStrategy.php#L123

You are right that it creates storage key based on only the URL and request method.

Comment: You are on to something here - actually the key is made from the uri, method AND headers.

So I should be able to make a key and added to the header. I'll give that a go, thanks.

Comment: Yeah they are just Vary headers. If you do not care about them then you can just make that method a one-liner.

Comment: Sort of - As far as I can see - the privateStrategy only caches if the right headers are set. That is not the case here :-(

I was able to make it work with the greedyStrategy and a namespace made from a md5(json_encoded($param));

Comment: I tried to do it myself, I submitted another answer. Please check it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Decided to look into it. You are right that it needs GreedyCacheStrategy because it literally caches everything regardless of any RFC standards.

Custom class for cache key creating.

```
class ParamsGreedyCacheStrategy extends GreedyCacheStrategy
{
    /**
     * Ignoring any headers, just straight up cache key based on method, URI, request body/params
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param KeyValueHttpHeader|null $varyHeaders
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getCacheKey(RequestInterface $request, KeyValueHttpHeader $varyHeaders = null)
    {
        return hash(
            'sha256',
            'greedy' . $request->getMethod() . $request->getUri() . $request->getBody()
        );
    }
}
```

Creating requests. I used Laravel caching here, you can use memcached. I also allow POST HTTP method to be cached, because by default only GET is being cached!

```
$handlerStack = HandlerStack::create();

$cacheMiddleware = new CacheMiddleware(
    new ParamsGreedyCacheStrategy(
        new LaravelCacheStorage(
            Cache::store('file')
        ),
        10
    )
);

// Not documented, but if you look at the source code they have methods for setting allowed HTTP methods. By default, only GET is allowed (per standards).
$cacheMiddleware->setHttpMethods(['GET' => true, 'POST' => true]);

$handlerStack->push(
    $cacheMiddleware,
    'cache'
);

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://example.org',
    'http_errors' => false,
    'handler' => $handlerStack
]);


for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $response = $client->post('/test', [
        'form_params' => ['val' => $i]
    ]);
    // Middleware attaches 'X-Kevinrob-Cache' header that let's us know if we hit the cache or not!
    dump($response->getHeader('X-Kevinrob-Cache'));
}
```